# How to classify data for Tensorflow.js as 2d, 3d etc?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Before I begin, I am completely new to machine learning and just starting to get my feet wet. I am sufficiently comfortable at JavaScript, and hence I thought I would give tensorflow.js a run. So please forgive my naivety.

I have data which contains information for an individual sample as:

```
Probes  Signal
1       150
2       320
3       15
4       40
.       .
.       .
10      200
```

Say I have 10 such known samples with different Signal levels for the probes. The probes and their order remain the same i.e. 1,2,3...10. This would be 3rd dimension?

My eventual aim is to create a model using these known samples. Then for the Unknown sample I would also have Probe (same order) and Signal data as given above, and the model should predict what is the sample (or closest related sample).

I am a little confused whether to represent this as a `tf.tensor2d` or `tf.tensor3d`

If it is tensor2d can I represent it in the manner so that each individual array will contain the Signal data:

`tf.tensor2d([[150, 320, 15, 40, ....., 200], [<data for sample2>], [<data for sample 3].....);`

If it is a tensor3d can I represent it in the manner so that it contains both the Probe number and the Signal data:

`tf.tensor3d([[[1,150], [2,320]], [[3,15], [4, 40],....,[10,200], [<data for sample2>], [<data for sample 3]);`

On one hand I feel a 2D tensor would be sufficient as the probe order remains the same, however please correct me if I am wrong in that assumption. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the probe ids(1-10) of your input data are consistant over each sample, you don't need to pass them to your model.

So your data is only one-dimensional, more specific it has the shape: `[10]`, which is also the shape of your first layer.

But since `model.fit()` and `model.predict()` take multiple samples as inputs they need  either one dimension more(`tensor2D`) or an array of tensors of the input shape of your first layer(`tensor1D[]`).

Comment: A little confused because I am a novice, but if I understand correctly I can either have a 1D tensor with array for each individual sample and pass this to the `model.fit` and `model.predict` as multiple tensors. Or a 2D tensor with an array of arrays for all the samples passed directly to the `model.fit` and `model.predict`?

Comment: Yes each of them would work, but it could be faster if you pass it as 2D, because then the model can batch process multiple samples at the same time easier.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.